# creating a nested json string with jq

Tags: json, shell, unix, jq

How can I create the below json with jq?

```
{"RedrivePolicy":{"deadLetterTargetArn":"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:12345678:reptar-dlq","maxReceiveCount":"15"}}
```

Comment: Every JSON value is also a valid jq program.  So the question as posed has a trivial answer.  Is that the question you meant to ask?

Comment: yes , it was indeed. I didn't realize it was simple.I have posted the answer which worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create the jq json using the command listed below -

```
redrive_policy=$(jq -n --arg arn "$dlq_arn" --arg max "$max_count" '{RedrivePolicy:{deadLetterTargetArn: $arn,maxReceiveCount: $max}}')
```

Answer (score 1):

if jq is not a strict requirement, alternatively you could do it using a unix walk-path utility **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/User%20Guide.md)**

```
bash $ <<<'{"RedrivePolicy":{"deadLetterTargetArn":"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:12345678:reptar-dlq","maxReceiveCount":"15"}}' jtc 
{
   "RedrivePolicy": {
      "deadLetterTargetArn": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:12345678:reptar-dlq",
      "maxReceiveCount": "15"
   }
}
bash $
```

and if you like to write it into the file, then do:

```
bash $ <<<'{"RedrivePolicy":{"deadLetterTargetArn":"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:12345678:reptar-dlq","maxReceiveCount":"15"}}' jtc - -f your.json
bash $ 
bash $ jtc your.json
{
   "RedrivePolicy": {
      "deadLetterTargetArn": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:12345678:reptar-dlq",
      "maxReceiveCount": "15"
   }
}
bash $
```

in fact, your output is a JSON, `jtc` here only validates it and saves into the file. If you don't need validation (and sure it's a valid JSON), then you could dump it right into the file:

```
bash $ <<<'{"RedrivePolicy":{"deadLetterTargetArn":"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:12345678:reptar-dlq","maxReceiveCount":"15"}}' cat >file.json
```

PS> Disclosure: I'm the creator of the `jtc` - shell cli tool for JSON operations

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry. This looks like a very useful tool. I only have jq installed in my jenkins env , so kind of mandated to use that. This is definitely one more tool in the toolbox which is helpful.